# regex to split numbers with sign from String

Tags: java

I have a string "M+147-168+80-0+0" and I want to split it like this [147,-168,80,0,0] using regex in java.

Comment: Dude, go for it - have a nice journey

Comment: May we ask if you are trying to write some sort of parser or calculator?  Regex isn't so smart that it can necessarily do everything you want by itself.

Comment: Make sure you read up on lookaheads and lookbehinds - I think you'll need those to solve this problem.

Answer (score -1):

```
ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList();
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[+-]\\d+");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("M+147-168+80-0+0");
while (matcher.find()) {
    list.add(Integer.parseInt(matcher.group()));
}
System.out.println(list);
```

Output:

```
[147, -168, 80, 0, 0]
```